# Speed up Yeoman? - How to avoid reinstalling packages/components

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, bower

When I nest yeoman generator projects (`D:/projects/` and `D:/projects/project2/`), it reinstalls all of the dependencies.

I thought node looks up the directory chain to find dependencies, so that they don't need to be reinstalled?

Is this a yeoman/generator thing?  Could a generator be configured to check for dependencies at a higher level, and skip the install?

Could this be configured with a separate `package.json` file?

I'd like to be able to stand up a generator in a matter of seconds, rather than minutes.  Currently I use plunker/jsfiddle instead of yeoman because its so much faster, however yeoman is obviously a better option.